# How should items that function at different baud rates work together?

Tags: camera, arduino, gprs, baud-rate

I've got an Arduino Uno which I'd like to setup to with a TTL Serial JPEG Camera for image capture and send that data using a GPRS shield.

Currently I've got the two pieces of hardware working independently.  The [camera](http://www.adafruit.com/products/613) is taking and storing photos.  The [GPRS shield](http://www.seeedstudio.com/wiki/GPRS_Shield_V2.0) is sending SMS, and connecting to web urls.

Now that I've confirmed both work in isolation, how do I combine the code?  The baud rate for the GPRS is set at 19200 and the camera at 9600.  I've tried to set the baud of the GPRS shield down to 9600 and while it 'runs' I don't get any response from the text message I tried to send.  Also the camera documentation says [not to change the baud rate](https://learn.adafruit.com/ttl-serial-camera/faq). Any guidance is appreciated

Answer (score 0):

Connect these two devices to two separate serial lines. Since you're on an Uno, which has only one hardware Serial line (pins 0 and 1), you can use [`SoftwareSerial`](http://arduino.cc/en/Reference/softwareSerial) to use another pair of pins as a second serial line.

Then you can simply specify different baud rates when setting each serial line up.